# "Referenced Libraries"-collapsable gone when checking out Eclipse project from SVN

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, libraries, subclipse

I have created an Eclipse project with a number of referenced jar files. I use a variable to specify the local folder of the jar files. However when I check out this project to another machine Eclipse does not organize the referenced files under a "Referenced Libraries" pin. Instead it just lists all of the files.

Any ideas why this happens and how to correct it?

Screenshot here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/clsj0.png

Comment: Image link is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking at the Project Explorer view. "Referenced Libraries" shows up in the **Package** Explorer view. (Use Window → Show View to open it.)

Also note that it won't show up in that view either, unless the "Show 'Referenced Libraries' Node" option is ticked in the view's options.

Answer (score 0):

Usually JavaEE is the default perspective. Change it to Java perspective by following below instructions:

Window -> Open Perspective -> Java

This should solve the problem.